# Password requirements with localization

Tags: java, apache-flex, localization

Our application currently checks user passwords to ensure that they are > 8 chars in length and include at least 1 uppercase character, 1 punctuation character, and 1 numeric character.  This is all well and good for English but now I'm tasked with localizing our app.  When it comes to character based languages like Chinese, Japanese, and Korean, I don't know how to proceed.

Do these languages use upper & lower case and punctuation etc.?  When googling, I find stuff about hirigana, katakana, and kanji etc. but I don't know what requirements to use to determine a secure password.  Any ideas?

Comment: Do you seriously believe a language not using the Latin alphabet can use such a policy? OK, with Cyrillic or Greek, it may. But Chinese, Japanese, Arabic?

Comment: That's the reason for my question.  We support 9 languages.  English, German, French, Spanish, Portuguese, Chinese-China, Chinese-Taiwan, Japanese, and Korean.  I believe my current code will work fine for all but the last 4.  I'm wondering how other apps handle this.  Is there a range of UTF-8 codes that correspond to specific chars that should be required etc.?

Comment: Well, Java's `Character` has `.isUpperCase()` etc, but I have no idea whether it applies to Chinese, Japanese or Korean... I don't even know whether these languages have such a notion at all!